# Why does this reducer not trigger a view change using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I'm building an application in redux and I ran into the problem outlined in the redux documentation where my view would not update after an action was dispatched. The documentation suggests that this happens when you mutate the state. The only problem is, I don't understand how what I was doing is considered a mutation:

```
case AppConstants.UPDATE_ALL_TIMERS:
    return action.timers
```

This, however, does work:

```
case AppConstants.UPDATE_ALL_TIMERS:
    let newState = state.map((timer, index) => {
        return action.timers[index]
    });
    return newState
```

How is it that just returning the value of the action as your new state is considered mutating the state? What am I missing?

Below is the entirety of my reducer, the two cases prior to UPDATE_ALL_TIMERS worked just fine. The reducer is being used with combine reducers and is only receiving the timers slice of state, which is an array of objects.

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case AppConstants.ADD_TIMER:
            let newState = [...state, action.timer];
            return newState
        case AppConstants.UPDATE_TIMER:
            newState = state.map((timer, index) => {
                if(index == action.timerID) {
                    const updatedTimer = {
                        ...timer,
                        elapsed: action.elapsed
                    }
                    return updatedTimer
                }
                return timer
            });
            return newState
        case AppConstants.UPDATE_ALL_TIMERS:
            newState = state.map((timer, index) => {
                return action.timers[index]
            });
            return newState
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of your reducer, and possibly the action creator as well?

Comment: Yes, without more context it's not clear why this would be an issue. Does something mess with any `timer` values?

Comment: edited to add the entirety of my reducer

Comment: Remember that your react components must be correctly `connect()`ed to redux for a refresh to happen on redux store change.

Comment: Can you also post your action creator?  Where is this "timers" part of the action coming from?

Comment: What are you passing in in `action.timers`? You shouldn't be passing your state into the reducer. What's the point? You already have them in your state.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your component ?

Usually when the Store state is alright and well updated yet the component do not re render it's because of deep nested mapped properties.

react-redux do not do deep checks to verify if a value has changed on deep nested mapped objects